# South African living in UK, need a Schengen visa. Where do we apply please? SA consulate or country of visit?

Tags: visas, schengen, south-african-citizens

Please can you let me know where I need to apply for a Schengen Visa, if I am living in the UK with a South African passport.  We have indefinite leave to remain status at present. Do we apply at the SA consulate, or at the consulate of the country that we are visiting? The website says only UK citizens can apply in London.

Comment: What website? Where are you going?

Comment: Why would UK citizens need to apply? Which website are you looking at?

Comment: For France either embassy ot tlscontact. For other countries VFS.

Answer (score 3):

The place to apply for a visa is always a representation of the the country you want to **visit**. (Or in certain cases, another country that handles visa application for the destination country. For example, the Danish embassy in London processes applications for visas to Iceland).

The South African consulate issues visas for visiting South Africa -- they can't help you get a visa for anywhere else.

For Schengen visas in particular, the rule is that you must apply to the consulate **of** the Schengen country that's the main destination of your trip, **in** the country where you're a legal resident. If you have indefinite leave to remain in the UK *and* an actual address there, that would be the appropriate Schengen country's consulate in the UK.

(Some countries have several consulates in the UK, such that you won't have to go to London if you live in Scotland, for example. That depends on which of the Schengen states you're going to).